# Upgrading PHP 5.1 to 5.3 on Linux Server

Tags: php, mysql, linux

I trying to find the best way to upgrade from PHP 5.1 to 5.3.  The CRM software I am running on this server requires this upgrade or else I probably wouldn't even perform it, because it seems like it's going to be perhaps trickier than I hoped it would be.  Being still new to the programming world, these routine upgrades are still worrisome to me.

I am running apache 2.2.6 (Fedora), PHP 5.1.6 and MySQL 5.0.27 on this server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the php version i gather that you're using Fedora core 6, which is way out of date. You should investigate upgrading to a OS where you can still get security updates like RHEL or Debian stable. Fedora is not really suited for servers due to the short support time.

Comment: Yes, you are correct, Fedora Core release 6.  The thing is, we are a small company, and I inherited most of the system administration duties even though I am not a sysadmin.  Upgrading the OS, along with these other packages might be beyond my expertise.  Is it like Ubuntu, where an upgrade will leave everything intact?

Comment: No it won't be like that.  But almost all settings will be stored in `/etc` so you should be able to do it pretty safely.  You could always try it on a VM if your company doesn't have funds for a test system.  Try VirtualBox.

Comment: Data is not preservered during upgrades. Fedora 13 will be released tomorrow, you can't skip versions during the upgrade, I think. That would be 7 upgrade steps, and I don't think the old repositories are still there, so it would not work anyway. In short, I wouldn't dare to try it.

I would strongly suggest to switch to an enterprise distribution, your CRM vendor certainly has a recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

A quick alternative to the upgrade is to install [Zend Server](http://www.zend.com/en/products/server-ce/), which provides with a standalone xAMP stack, including either PHP 5.2 or 5.3.